# How to uninstall from Command Prompt programms that where not installed by Windows Installer?

Tags: windows, cmd, exe, wmic

I created an electron app and with the use of `eletron-packager` and then `electron-squirrel-startup` I created an installer `.exe` file.

Installation works fine,  but I am unsure how I can uninstall this program from `cmd`. I can uninstall it from the Control Panel, but I would like to use `cmd`. I found some answers about uninstalling from Command Prompt with

`wmic` and `product get name`

but as my program was not installed by Windows Installer,  I cannot find the name on the product list and even if I did, not sure if that's the way to do it.

Comment: Do you have a product code like this? `{1D5B92F4-4567-12EB-B12F-8BF78C93CCAE}`

Comment: Nope, I don't have a code like this on the product list generated by `product get name` .

Comment: Typically, the Add/Remove Programs control panel just runs a command line retrieved from the registry.  Find the key for your software package in `SOFTWARE\[Wow6432Node]\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and see what the value for `UninstallString` is.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I can't fing my program in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` nor in `HKLM\Software\[Wow6432Node]\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

is it possible that my program is not listed there?

Comment: If it was a per-user installation it would be somewhere in HKCU instead.